# Seamless cell fracture?

Tags: cell-fracture

How do we create a cell fracture that appears seamless before an animated dynamic paint reveals the cracks? I already have the dynamic paint brush animated and effecting the weight on a smooth modifier. I just need to make the cracks appear seamless.

Answer (score 3):

Before you fracture it you should have custom normals on the mesh. You can also transfer normals from the original mesh by selecting faces by material assignments if you have a separate material for internal faces.

In addition to that you can swap out the original mesh with the fracture at the frame when it breaks.

Comment: So how does this work exactly? I keep trying Custom normals on original mesh and than data transfer on fractured mesh from original with Face Corner Data > Custom Normals checked